# making SQL more efficiency by making two queries into one instead of having a loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code and was wondering how I could simplify it into one MYSQL statement

```
$sql = "SELECT sesionID 
FROM  `juegos_sesiones` 
WHERE  `usuarioID` = ".$_SESSION['MM_UserID'];


$query = mysql_query($sql, $cnx) or die(mysql_error());
//$row_rsPaises = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPaises);
$exercises = mysql_num_rows($query);

echo $exercises;

//find total points

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$sql2 = 'SELECT correct_answers FROM `juegos_sesiones_detalle`  WHERE  `sesionID`  = '.$row['sesionID'];


$query2 = mysql_query($sql2, $cnx) or die(mysql_error());
$details2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
$counter = $counter + $details2['correct_answers'];

}

echo '<br />'.$counter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(correct_answers) as total_correct_answers
FROM `juegos_sesiones_detalle` d
INNER JOIN  `juegos_sesiones` s on s.`sesionID` = d.`sesionID`
WHERE  `usuarioID` = $_SESSION['MM_UserID']
```

You can read about joins [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: when i do this i get 385, and before I got 2712 - i dont know why id get a different number?

Comment: ok now ive seen, im getting 335 rows back with lots of values in correct_answers, i need to get the total of correct answers

Answer (score 1):

You can write single query by using `INNER JOIN`  as:

```
SELECT correct_answers
FROM juegos_sesiones_detalle a
    INNER JOIN juegos_sesiones b
        ON a.sesionID = b.usuarioID;
```

Comment: this doesnt worked because both tables are linked with sesionID

Comment: try now with INNER JOIN ON a.sesionID = b.usuarioID;

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT correct_answers FROM `juegos_sesiones_detalle` jsd
        JOIN `juegos_sesiones` js
        ON jsd.sesionID = js.`sesionID`
        WHERE js.usuarioID = ".$_SESSION['MM_UserID'];
```